# mod_rewrite rules to run fcgi for different subdomains

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, .htaccess, django, shared-hosting

On my shared hosting server (Hostmonster) I have django (actually pinax) setup so that a .htaccess mod_rewrite rule rewrites the request to a pinax.fcgi file:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ pinax.fcgi/$1 [QSA,L]
```

What I would like to do is have a different pinax.fcgi file get called depending on the domain used (or subdomain), something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ pinax2.fcgi/$1 [QSA,L]


RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ pinax.fcgi/$1 [QSA,L]
```

This is stored in a .htaccess file in my ROOT public_html folder (not in the public_html/subdomain/ folder), but unfortunately just results in internal redirect errors. How can I write these rules so that they use a different fcgi file for different domains?

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out.

In the root .htaccess (in public_html) put:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^subdomain\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ pinax.fcgi/$1 [QSA,L]
```

In your subdomain .htaccess (in public_html/subdomain) put:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ pinax2.fcgi/$1 [QSA,L]
```

pinax2.fcgi needs to be in the public_html/subdomain/ directory, and pinax.fcgi should be in public_html/

Comment: You deserve more +1s for this - I've been hunting a solution for hours!